# vtiger customer portal php 5.4 patch

Tags: php, patch, vtiger

When i migrate to php version in my server . the vtiger customer portal not working current version of php is version 5.3.2 . in this version vtiger 6 working fine .

Is that any patch available for download for vtiger customer portal php 5.4 patch .

i an add .htaccess file like that in customer portal

```
  # Use PHP 5.3
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-5.3 .php
```

But the index.php file open in browser what is in that file.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no current vTiger v6.0 patch for PHP5.4.x. There is however a (3rd party) patch for vTiger v5.4.0 which will allow it to run on PHP5.4+. Have a look here: https://forums.vtiger.com/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=54593&start=10#p172298

I have also read that vTiger v6.1 will support PHP5.4+ but we'll have to wait and see...

Comment: It`s all about **Vtiger**  i need **vtiger customer portal**

Comment: Sorry I misread your question... I haven't used vTiger customer portal so am unfamiliar with it. If I come across an answer to your q I will post it.